# SparkR - Extracting Month from Date Field

Tags: date, sparkr, databricks

I am using Databricks and SparkR, trying to extract the month from a Date field but keep getting the following error, when trying to using the function month():

Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) :
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

If I use dayofmonth()it runs perfectly so I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Here is a sample of the fields i am trying to work with.

$ Net_due_date    : Date 2017-10-06 2017-10-05 2018-01-17 2017-12-23 2017-08-20 2018-01-17
$ Clearing_Date   : Date 2017-10-06 2017-10-17 1900-01-01 2017-12-26 2017-08-24 2018-01-19

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without a reproducible example, but try casting the column to timestamp first.

```
df$Net_due_date_month <- month(cast(df$Net_due_date, 'timestamp'))
```

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new here so not sure how to add a reproducible example, except for the data i included above. I tried your solution but get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a small subset of your data so that the error is replicated. I suspect that your date column are not date format.

You can try any of these below:

```
library(lubridate)

df$Net_due_date_month <- month(as.Date(df$Net_due_date, format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

or

```
df$Net_due_date_month <- month(as.POSIXlt(df$Net_due_date, format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
```